# Typescript mongoose models with discriminator throw an error as incompatible property error

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mongoose

I want to create a mongo model with discriminator. And there are baseModel and and Tiktok campaign model. So, my Campaign Model like that:

```
export interface BaseCampaignInterface {
    ...
    ...
    image_id : string;
    bid : number;
}

const baseCampaignSchema = new Schema<BaseCampaignInterface>({
    ...
    ...
    image_id : { type: String, required: false},
    bid : { type : Number, required : false}
}, baseOptions);

export const BaseCampaignModel = model("Campaign", baseCampaignSchema);

export interface TikTokCampaignInterface {
    ...
    ...
    profile_image : string;
    ad_id : string
}
export interface TikTokCampaignDocument extends TikTokCampaignInterface, Document {
    minify(): unknown;
}

export interface TikTokCampaignModel extends Model<TikTokCampaignDocument> { }

export const TikTokCampaignSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    ...
    profile_image : { type : String},
    ad_id : { type : String }
});


export const TikTokModel = BaseCampaignModel.discriminator<
    TikTokCampaignDocument,
    TikTokCampaignModel
>("TikTokCampaign", TikTokCampaignSchema); ===>>>> error line
```

But when I start my server I getting an error like that:

```
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes);
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/models/CampaignModel.ts:83:21 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Schema<Document<any, any, any>, Model<any, any, any>, undefined, any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Schema<TikTokCampaignDocument, TikTokCampaignModel, undefined, unknown>'.
  Types of property 'plugin' are incompatible.
    Type '(fn: (schema: Schema<Document<any, any, any>, Model<Document<any, any, any>, {}, {}>, undefined, {}>, opts?: any) => void, opts?: any) => Schema<...>' is not assignable to type '(fn: (schema: Schema<TikTokCampaignDocument, Model<TikTokCampaignDocument, {}, {}>, undefined, {}>, opts?: any) => void, opts?: any) => Schema<...>'.
      Types of parameters 'fn' and 'fn' are incompatible.
        Types of parameters 'schema' and 'schema' are incompatible.
          Type 'Schema<Document<any, any, any>, Model<Document<any, any, any>, {}, {}>, undefined, {}>' is not assignable to type 'Schema<TikTokCampaignDocument, Model<TikTokCampaignDocument, {}, {}>, undefined, {}>'.
            Types of property 'static' are incompatible.
              Type '{ (name: string, fn: (this: Model<Document<any, any, any>, {}, {}>, ...args: any[]) => any): Schema<Document<any, any, any>, Model<Document<any, any, any>, {}, {}>, undefined, {}>; (obj: { ...; }): Schema<...>; }' is not assignable to type '{ (name: string, fn: (this: Model<TikTokCampaignDocument, {}, {}>, ...args: any[]) => any): Schema<TikTokCampaignDocument, Model<TikTokCampaignDocument, {}, {}>, undefined, {}>; (obj: { ...; }): Schema<...>; }'.
                Types of parameters 'fn' and 'fn' are incompatible.
                  The 'this' types of each signature are incompatible.
                    Type 'Model<Document<any, any, any>, {}, {}>' is not assignable to type 'Model<TikTokCampaignDocument, {}, {}>'.
                      The types returned by 'count(...).$where(...).exec()' are incompatible between these types.
                        Type 'Promise<Document<any, any, any>[]>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<TikTokCampaignDocument[]>'.
                          Type 'Document<any, any, any>[]' is not assignable to type 'TikTokCampaignDocument[]'.

83 >("TikTokCampaign", TikTokCampaignSchema);
```

Why Im getting this error? How Can I solve this? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue in the latest version of Mongoose when getting the type property, check [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/10537):

I reverted back to `5.12.11` (following a guide where that was the version used - you may not need to go that far back), and the issue no longer appeared.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved in 5.13.7(ref). Updating mongoose version worked fine for me